# Sorting a matrix with symbolic variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, symbolic-math

How can i sort or arrange this matrix ? The 10th row is showing up now in the very start while it should follow the sequence and comes at 10th place. Few other elements are also misplaced in the middle. All the variables are symbolic in this case. Thank you.

```
[ P10_1, P10_10, P10_2, P10_3, P10_4, P10_5, P10_6, P10_7, P10_8, P10_9, P1_1, P1_10, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, P1_5, P1_6, P1_7, P1_8, P1_9, P2_1, P2_10, P2_2, P2_3, P2_4, P2_5, P2_6, P2_7, P2_8, P2_9, P3_1, P3_10, P3_2, P3_3, P3_4, P3_5, P3_6, P3_7, P3_8, P3_9, P4_1, P4_10, P4_2, P4_3, P4_4, P4_5, P4_6, P4_7, P4_8, P4_9, P5_1, P5_10, P5_2, P5_3, P5_4, P5_5, P5_6, P5_7, P5_8, P5_9, P6_1, P6_10, P6_2, P6_3, P6_4, P6_5, P6_6, P6_7, P6_8, P6_9, P7_1, P7_10, P7_2, P7_3, P7_4, P7_5, P7_6, P7_7, P7_8, P7_9, P8_1, P8_10, P8_2, P8_3, P8_4, P8_5, P8_6, P8_7, P8_8, P8_9, P9_1, P9_10, P9_2, P9_3, P9_4, P9_5, P9_6, P9_7, P9_8, P9_9]
```

The sort function return this.The 10th row should come in the end but it is appearing in the start.

```
[ P10_1, P10_2, P10_3, P10_4, P10_5, P10_6, P10_7, P10_8, P10_9, P10_10, P1_1, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, P1_5, P1_6, P1_7, P1_8, P1_9, P2_1, P2_2, P2_3, P2_4, P2_5, P2_6, P2_7, P2_8, P2_9, P3_1, P3_2, P3_3, P3_4, P3_5, P3_6, P3_7, P3_8, P3_9, P4_1, P4_2, P4_3, P4_4, P4_5, P4_6, P4_7, P4_8, P4_9, P5_1, P5_2, P5_3, P5_4, P5_5, P5_6, P5_7, P5_8, P5_9, P6_1, P6_2, P6_3, P6_4, P6_5, P6_6, P6_7, P6_8, P6_9, P7_1, P7_2, P7_3, P7_4, P7_5, P7_6, P7_7, P7_8, P7_9, P8_1, P8_2, P8_3, P8_4, P8_5, P8_6, P8_7, P8_8, P8_9, P9_1, P9_2, P9_3, P9_4, P9_5, P9_6, P9_7, P9_8, P9_9, P1_10, P2_10, P3_10, P4_10, P5_10, P6_10, P7_10, P8_10, P9_10]
```

Comment: You can get `second_mat` using `sort(first_Mat)` but I am not sure if I understood your question right.

Comment: Please update your question to show how your symbolic variables are created. Do you use something like `P = sym('P',10)`? If you use `P = sym('P0%d_0%d',10)` (see documentation for `sym`), sorting work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

horchler suggested in the comments to create proper variable names to make lexicographic sorting using `sort` work properly. I think this is a very good idea, but unfortunately the format string he suggests does not work. It always pads a zero, ending up with this:

```
>> P1 = sym('P0%d_0%d',10)

P =

[  P01_01,  P01_02,  P01_03,  P01_04,  P01_05,  P01_06,  P01_07,  P01_08,  P01_09,  P01_010]
[  P02_01,  P02_02,  P02_03,  P02_04,  P02_05,  P02_06,  P02_07,  P02_08,  P02_09,  P02_010]
[  P03_01,  P03_02,  P03_03,  P03_04,  P03_05,  P03_06,  P03_07,  P03_08,  P03_09,  P03_010]
[  P04_01,  P04_02,  P04_03,  P04_04,  P04_05,  P04_06,  P04_07,  P04_08,  P04_09,  P04_010]
[  P05_01,  P05_02,  P05_03,  P05_04,  P05_05,  P05_06,  P05_07,  P05_08,  P05_09,  P05_010]
[  P06_01,  P06_02,  P06_03,  P06_04,  P06_05,  P06_06,  P06_07,  P06_08,  P06_09,  P06_010]
[  P07_01,  P07_02,  P07_03,  P07_04,  P07_05,  P07_06,  P07_07,  P07_08,  P07_09,  P07_010]
[  P08_01,  P08_02,  P08_03,  P08_04,  P08_05,  P08_06,  P08_07,  P08_08,  P08_09,  P08_010]
[  P09_01,  P09_02,  P09_03,  P09_04,  P09_05,  P09_06,  P09_07,  P09_08,  P09_09,  P09_010]
[ P010_01, P010_02, P010_03, P010_04, P010_05, P010_06, P010_07, P010_08, P010_09, P010_010]
```

I tried to fix the format string but failed. MATLAB refuses to accept the format string which would be needed:

```
>> P1 = sym('P%.2d_%.2d',10)
Error using sym>createCharMatrix (line
2172)
Symbolic matrix base name must be a
simple variable name.

Error in sym>convertCharWithOption
(line 2138)
        s = createCharMatrix(x,a);

Error in sym>tomupad (line 1871)
        S = convertCharWithOption(x,a);

Error in sym (line 109)
            S.s = tomupad(x,a);
```

So I wrote my own function to fix this:

```
function [ s ] = symMatrix( A,set )
%preallocate an empty matrix to fill it in the loop
s=sym(zeros(set));
%just some math t get the required amount of digits.
digits=ceil(log10(max(set)+1));
%generate format string with required digits. Check documentation of sprintf for details
format=['%s%.',num2str(digits),'d_%.',num2str(digits),'d'];
%finally go through the matrix...
for r=1:set(1)
    for c=1:set(2)
       %...get the right name for each variable ....
       sprintf(format,A,r,c);
       %...and create a variable with that name.
       s(r,c)=sym(n);
    end
end
end
```

Which produces this result:

```
>> P2=symMatrix('P',[11,11])

P2 =

[ P01_01, P01_02, P01_03, P01_04, P01_05, P01_06, P01_07, P01_08, P01_09, P01_10, P01_11]
[ P02_01, P02_02, P02_03, P02_04, P02_05, P02_06, P02_07, P02_08, P02_09, P02_10, P02_11]
[ P03_01, P03_02, P03_03, P03_04, P03_05, P03_06, P03_07, P03_08, P03_09, P03_10, P03_11]
[ P04_01, P04_02, P04_03, P04_04, P04_05, P04_06, P04_07, P04_08, P04_09, P04_10, P04_11]
[ P05_01, P05_02, P05_03, P05_04, P05_05, P05_06, P05_07, P05_08, P05_09, P05_10, P05_11]
[ P06_01, P06_02, P06_03, P06_04, P06_05, P06_06, P06_07, P06_08, P06_09, P06_10, P06_11]
[ P07_01, P07_02, P07_03, P07_04, P07_05, P07_06, P07_07, P07_08, P07_09, P07_10, P07_11]
[ P08_01, P08_02, P08_03, P08_04, P08_05, P08_06, P08_07, P08_08, P08_09, P08_10, P08_11]
[ P09_01, P09_02, P09_03, P09_04, P09_05, P09_06, P09_07, P09_08, P09_09, P09_10, P09_11]
[ P10_01, P10_02, P10_03, P10_04, P10_05, P10_06, P10_07, P10_08, P10_09, P10_10, P10_11]
[ P11_01, P11_02, P11_03, P11_04, P11_05, P11_06, P11_07, P11_08, P11_09, P11_10, P11_11]
```

Finally compare the sorting of all three possibilities:

```
>> P3=sym('P',[11,11])

P3 =

[  P1_1,  P1_2,  P1_3,  P1_4,  P1_5,  P1_6,  P1_7,  P1_8,  P1_9,  P1_10,  P1_11]
[  P2_1,  P2_2,  P2_3,  P2_4,  P2_5,  P2_6,  P2_7,  P2_8,  P2_9,  P2_10,  P2_11]
[  P3_1,  P3_2,  P3_3,  P3_4,  P3_5,  P3_6,  P3_7,  P3_8,  P3_9,  P3_10,  P3_11]
[  P4_1,  P4_2,  P4_3,  P4_4,  P4_5,  P4_6,  P4_7,  P4_8,  P4_9,  P4_10,  P4_11]
[  P5_1,  P5_2,  P5_3,  P5_4,  P5_5,  P5_6,  P5_7,  P5_8,  P5_9,  P5_10,  P5_11]
[  P6_1,  P6_2,  P6_3,  P6_4,  P6_5,  P6_6,  P6_7,  P6_8,  P6_9,  P6_10,  P6_11]
[  P7_1,  P7_2,  P7_3,  P7_4,  P7_5,  P7_6,  P7_7,  P7_8,  P7_9,  P7_10,  P7_11]
[  P8_1,  P8_2,  P8_3,  P8_4,  P8_5,  P8_6,  P8_7,  P8_8,  P8_9,  P8_10,  P8_11]
[  P9_1,  P9_2,  P9_3,  P9_4,  P9_5,  P9_6,  P9_7,  P9_8,  P9_9,  P9_10,  P9_11]
[ P10_1, P10_2, P10_3, P10_4, P10_5, P10_6, P10_7, P10_8, P10_9, P10_10, P10_11]
[ P11_1, P11_2, P11_3, P11_4, P11_5, P11_6, P11_7, P11_8, P11_9, P11_10, P11_11]


>> sort(P1(:)).' %P1 = sym('P0%d_0%d',10)

ans =

[ P01_01, P01_02, P01_03, P01_04, P01_05, P01_06, P01_07, P01_08, P01_09, P02_01, P02_02, P02_03, P02_04, P02_05, P02_06, P02_07, P02_08, P02_09, P03_01, P03_02, P03_03, P03_04, P03_05, P03_06, P03_07, P03_08, P03_09, P04_01, P04_02, P04_03, P04_04, P04_05, P04_06, P04_07, P04_08, P04_09, P05_01, P05_02, P05_03, P05_04, P05_05, P05_06, P05_07, P05_08, P05_09, P06_01, P06_02, P06_03, P06_04, P06_05, P06_06, P06_07, P06_08, P06_09, P07_01, P07_02, P07_03, P07_04, P07_05, P07_06, P07_07, P07_08, P07_09, P08_01, P08_02, P08_03, P08_04, P08_05, P08_06, P08_07, P08_08, P08_09, P09_01, P09_02, P09_03, P09_04, P09_05, P09_06, P09_07, P09_08, P09_09, P010_01, P010_02, P010_03, P010_04, P010_05, P010_06, P010_07, P010_08, P010_09, P01_010, P02_010, P03_010, P04_010, P05_010, P06_010, P07_010, P08_010, P09_010, P010_010]

>> sort(P2(:)).' %P2=symMatrix('P',[11,11])

ans =

[ P01_01, P01_02, P01_03, P01_04, P01_05, P01_06, P01_07, P01_08, P01_09, P01_10, P01_11, P02_01, P02_02, P02_03, P02_04, P02_05, P02_06, P02_07, P02_08, P02_09, P02_10, P02_11, P03_01, P03_02, P03_03, P03_04, P03_05, P03_06, P03_07, P03_08, P03_09, P03_10, P03_11, P04_01, P04_02, P04_03, P04_04, P04_05, P04_06, P04_07, P04_08, P04_09, P04_10, P04_11, P05_01, P05_02, P05_03, P05_04, P05_05, P05_06, P05_07, P05_08, P05_09, P05_10, P05_11, P06_01, P06_02, P06_03, P06_04, P06_05, P06_06, P06_07, P06_08, P06_09, P06_10, P06_11, P07_01, P07_02, P07_03, P07_04, P07_05, P07_06, P07_07, P07_08, P07_09, P07_10, P07_11, P08_01, P08_02, P08_03, P08_04, P08_05, P08_06, P08_07, P08_08, P08_09, P08_10, P08_11, P09_01, P09_02, P09_03, P09_04, P09_05, P09_06, P09_07, P09_08, P09_09, P09_10, P09_11, P10_01, P10_02, P10_03, P10_04, P10_05, P10_06, P10_07, P10_08, P10_09, P10_10, P10_11, P11_01, P11_02, P11_03, P11_04, P11_05, P11_06, P11_07, P11_08, P11_09, P11_10, P11_11]

>> sort(P3(:)).' %P3 = sym('P',10) 

ans =

[ P10_1, P10_2, P10_3, P10_4, P10_5, P10_6, P10_7, P10_8, P10_9, P11_1, P11_2, P11_3, P11_4, P11_5, P11_6, P11_7, P11_8, P11_9, P10_10, P10_11, P11_10, P11_11, P1_1, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, P1_5, P1_6, P1_7, P1_8, P1_9, P2_1, P2_2, P2_3, P2_4, P2_5, P2_6, P2_7, P2_8, P2_9, P3_1, P3_2, P3_3, P3_4, P3_5, P3_6, P3_7, P3_8, P3_9, P4_1, P4_2, P4_3, P4_4, P4_5, P4_6, P4_7, P4_8, P4_9, P5_1, P5_2, P5_3, P5_4, P5_5, P5_6, P5_7, P5_8, P5_9, P6_1, P6_2, P6_3, P6_4, P6_5, P6_6, P6_7, P6_8, P6_9, P7_1, P7_2, P7_3, P7_4, P7_5, P7_6, P7_7, P7_8, P7_9, P8_1, P8_2, P8_3, P8_4, P8_5, P8_6, P8_7, P8_8, P8_9, P9_1, P9_2, P9_3, P9_4, P9_5, P9_6, P9_7, P9_8, P9_9, P1_10, P1_11, P2_10, P2_11, P3_10, P3_11, P4_10, P4_11, P5_10, P5_11, P6_10, P6_11, P7_10, P7_11, P8_10, P8_11, P9_10, P9_11]
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm my problem with `sym('P%.2d_%.2d',10)` in a more recent MATLAB version? I am using R2013a

Comment: After performing sorting on P3 why it starts with `P10_1`. Why not with `P1_1`

Comment: @AAhmed: P2 uses the code I suggested and should be sorted correct, P3 is just for reference.

Comment: When i sort `P2`, It is not giving me the correct result as shown by you. This Matlab version is very old. May be that's the reason.

Comment: @AAhmed: Does it properly sort text data? Try `sort(arrayfun(@char,P2(:).','uni',false))`

Comment: @Danel: Your function works like a charm on my office PC (R2014a).
Thank you so much. Can you explain your function to me that how it operates as i am not that much good in Matlab ?

Comment: Btw, i deleted that other question as your solution took care of that problem as well. Million Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with "symbolic"? When it's a string, simple parse them as numbers (remove 'P' and replace the underscore '_' with a dot '.').
Finally sort while saving the indices.

```
this = '[ P10_1, P10_10, P10_2, P10_3, P10_4, P10_5, P10_6, P10_7, P10_8, P10_9, P1_1, P1_10, P1_2, P1_3, P1_4, P1_5, P1_6, P1_7, P1_8, P1_9, P2_1, P2_10, P2_2, P2_3, P2_4, P2_5, P2_6, P2_7, P2_8, P2_9, P3_1, P3_10, P3_2, P3_3, P3_4, P3_5, P3_6, P3_7, P3_8, P3_9, P4_1, P4_10, P4_2, P4_3, P4_4, P4_5, P4_6, P4_7, P4_8, P4_9, P5_1, P5_10, P5_2, P5_3, P5_4, P5_5, P5_6, P5_7, P5_8, P5_9, P6_1, P6_10, P6_2, P6_3, P6_4, P6_5, P6_6, P6_7, P6_8, P6_9, P7_1, P7_10, P7_2, P7_3, P7_4, P7_5, P7_6, P7_7, P7_8, P7_9, P8_1, P8_10, P8_2, P8_3, P8_4, P8_5, P8_6, P8_7, P8_8, P8_9, P9_1, P9_10, P9_2, P9_3, P9_4, P9_5, P9_6, P9_7, P9_8, P9_9]';

% this is the ugly part :)
original = regexp([regexprep(this, {'\[','\]'}, {'',''}) ','], '(.*?),', 'tokens');
m = eval(regexprep(this, {'_', 'P'},{'.',''}));

[s, idx] = sort(m);

original(idx)
```

As you see, this just works partly, because "symbolic" `P10_1 < P10_10`, but on numeric level, they're equal. So you just need to figure out to handle it, e.g. ensure you always have two decimal places and complete a leading zero if not.

If it's not a string, ignore this :)

Comment: Symbolic variables are part of the [symbolic math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic)

Comment: ...but they are represented as strings in workspace (and `whos`) too. A more elegant way is to put every symbolic variable in a structured list with an additional field as the value and simple sort the structured list...

Comment: They are instances of the class `sym` in the workspace.